# XPath Syntax - XSL 1.0

Tags: xpath, syntax, xslt-1.0, nodes

I'm trying to select all elements using XSL and XPath syntax where there is more than one pickup. I'd like to return the counter_name for each. Can someone please help me with the syntax? In this example there is only one counter_name with pickup locations, but there could be multiple locations where there are pickup counters.

**XPATH**

```
 <xsl:value-of select="results/unique_locations/partner_location_ids[count(pickup) &gt; 0]/counter_name" /><br/>
```

**XML**

```
<results>
<unique_locations>
    <counter_name>Lake Buena Vista, FL</counter_name>
    <is_airport>N</is_airport>
    <partner_location_ids>
        <pickup>
        </pickup>
        <dropoff>
            <container>ZR-ORLS001</container>
            <container>ET-ORLR062</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLS011</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLW015</container>
            <container>AV-ORLR004</container>
        </dropoff>
    </partner_location_ids>
    <counter_name>Orlando, FL</counter_name>
    <is_airport>N</is_airport>
    <partner_location_ids>
        <pickup>
            <container>ET-ORLC037</container>
            <container>AV-ORLC021</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC033</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC035</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLS007</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC004</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC002</container>
            <container>ZR-ORLS002</container>
            <container>BU-ORLE002</container>
            <container>AV-ORLC019</container>
            <container>ET-ORLR064</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC001</container>
            <container>ET-ORLR063</container>
            <container>ET-ORLR061</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC011</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC054</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLN003</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC007</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC005</container>
            <container>ZA-ORLC002</container>
            <container>ZA-ORLC003</container>
            <container>ZA-ORLC001</container>
            <container>AV-ORLC002</container>
            <container>AV-ORLC001</container>
            <container>BU-ORLS001</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC012</container>
            <container>AL-ORLR071</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC022</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC051</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC025</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLN018</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC017</container>
            <container>AV-ORLN003</container>
            <container>BU-ORLC002</container>
            <container>BU-ORLC003</container>
            <container>BU-ORLS006</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC027</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC022</container>
            <container>AL-ORLR081</container>
            <container>BU-ORLC005</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLR029</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC032</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC031</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC030</container>
            <container>ET-ORLC021</container>
        </pickup>
        <dropoff>
            <container>HZ-ORLC003</container>
            <container>ZA-ORLC004</container>
            <container>BU-ORLW002</container>
            <container>HZ-ORLC026</container>
            <container>ZR-ORLC010</container>
            <container>AL-ORLR073</container>
        </dropoff>
    </partner_location_ids>
</unique_locations>
```

Comment: Your XPath references a `<results>` element that does not appear in your XML.  It fails to reference the `<container>` element nested inside `<unique_locations>`.

Comment: The `count(pickup) &gt; 0` predicate, is more complicated than it needs to be -- just `pickup` would suffice.  Except that it does not match your prose: both variations give you "at least one" not "more than one" pickup.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated the XML. If a pickup element exists, but does not have any child elements. I'm only concerned if a pickup element has child elements.

Comment: So what's the minimum number of children a `pickup` must have to satisfy the criterion?  One?

Comment: Yes 1 @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 0):

Your XML structure is non-ideal, in that it appears to contain elements that are associated with each other by sequence, rather than exclusively by containment within the same element.  But XPath can deal with that.

Supposing that the context node for evaluation of the XPath is the parent node of the `<results>` whose contents you are examining, it appears you want something along these lines:

```
results/unique_locations/partner_location_ids[pickup/*]/preceding-sibling::counter_name
```

Note in the first place the predicate: `[pickup/*]`.  The expression within, interpreted in boolean context, evaluates to true if the expression matches any nodes.  That's why we need `pickup/*`, not just `pickup`, to distinguish between `<pickup>` elements that contain child nodes and those that don't.

Additionally, observe the use of the `preceding-sibling` axis instead of the default `child` axis to step from each matching `<partner_location_ids>` to its corresponding (I think) `<counter_name>`.